# Calling Oracle Stored Procedure From Classic ASP

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, asp-classic

here is a snippet of my code:

```
  Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = objCon
       cmd.CommandType = 4
    cmd.CommandText = "SP_USERLOGIN"

       response.Write(p_user_id)
       cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter ("User_locked",adVarChar, adParamInput)
        cmd.parameters(0).value = p_user_id
       cmd.Execute
```

When i try to Append the parameter, i get the following error:

> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are
>   in conflict with one another.

my stored procedure only takes 1 parameter:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE        SP_USERLOGIN ( User_locked VARCHAR2 ) as
BEGIN
update tusers Set user_account_status='status' where user_id = User_locked;
commit;
END;
```

Comment: Just a guess, but you may need to specify the varchar length in the `CreateParameter` call: `... CreateParameter("User_locked", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30)`. The 30 is just an example; put in whatever will cover the longest string you ever expect to pass.

Comment: i made your change, but am getting the same error

Comment: What's the value of `p_user_id`? If it's null there may be problems. Sorry, that's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: no, it's text. i'm displaying it before adding the parameter. even if i hard code the parameter value in, i get the same result...   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter ("xx", adVarChar, adParamInput,24,p_user_id)

Comment: Do you know for sure if the values like `adVarChar` are defined? I see you're using `4` instead of `adCmdStoredProc`. `adVarChar` = `200` and `adParamInput` = `1`, so could you try `cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter ("User_locked", 200, 1, 30)`?

Comment: different error! now we are getting somehwere: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00201: identifier 'SP_USERLOGIN' must be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored. i guess it can't find the stored procedure? but i'm able to execute it within SQLPlus just fine...

Comment: aaaaa, never mind! it worked! i had to add schema name before sp name and it worked!. please post as answer and i'll mark it as correct :) thanks again!

Comment: That's great news! I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the constants such as `adVarChar`, etc. weren't defined. There may have been a second problem with the length of the parameter not defined (that's the 4th argument)

There's a file name `ADOVBS.INC` that defines these, and if it isn't included then the constant *values* must be used instead.

To problem went away when this...

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter ("User_locked",adVarChar, adParamInput)
```

... was changed to this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter ("User_locked",200, 1, 30)
```

The `30` above is a length value for the `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

A tiny (Oracle) workaround for replacing the clumsy cmd object and its parameter handling.
Suppose you want to execute PROC1, a stored procedure and pass it two parameters. You make a dummy table called DUMMY with two fields corresponding in type to the parameters. You insert one row with values whatever. You make a before-update trigger to DUMMY. The trigger must do exactly the same thing as PROC1 would and reads its parameters as fields of the "updated" record (:new.a, :new.b).
In ASP you use an "update schema.dummy set a=..., b=..." statement and that's it.
Disadvantage: unorthodoxy.
Advantage: cleaner ASP code; easy debugging.
+ return parameters possible the same way backwards, reading the dummy table (any table, by the way).